# React Native Android build : Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: react-native

I keep getting this error when trying to generate the APK for my project. I use react native 0.61.5 and I don't install any library.

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My work\ReactNative\AwesomeProject61\android>gradle
w bundleRelease

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My
info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 1 asset files
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My'
error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My'. Run
CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Desktop\My work\ReactNative\AwesomeProject61\android>
```

Comment: For me the only thing that works was changing the My Documents folder name to Documents, the space in the folder's name was the problem and by your log seems to be the same problem.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried cleaning your Gradle?

Please try this command `cd android && ./gradlew clean`  run this command on your project's root directory! or `./gradlew clean` in your project's android folder.

after that recompile the App .

If the above solution does not help, try building your release with this command, go to your android folder and run command `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: I too facing this issue, recently but this above solution is not working for me. Actually I tried to export Signed apk. Give any other solution for this problem

Comment: works for me: `cd android && ./gradlew clean` then in android folder `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` this command skips bundle and app crashes on start

Answer (score 7):

The following command works for me:

```
gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Comment: I still have this problem

Comment: YOU CAN TRY WITH  ./gradlew app:assembleRelease

Answer (score 2):

Removing the space in one of the folders of the project directory solved this issue for me.

from D:\Work Stuff\Project\android
to D:\WorkStuff\Project\android

Then I ran:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --stop
```

Afterwards `./gradlew bundleRelease` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/)

Then `cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
.\gradlew app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Answer (score 0):

after accordingly install and deploy the keystore file based on documentation use the following line of command to build apk

```
.\gradlew app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -3):

update your **Visual C++** and it will fix the issue.

you can download it using this link: [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)